# Not able to minify JS/CSS for wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, caching, minify, google-pagespeed

I am working for google pagespeed insight score. website is wordpress, I have tried with all possible cache plugins. it breaks the UI in the end. tried to minify only inline css/JS though same results. may be it does not detect the optimization and so it force-applies its minification on the already minified files and breaks the UI.

Implemented the GZIP compression and leverage browser caching in .htaccess, still getting warnings for Enable compression.

So how can i get better insight score with this issues?, it is hosted on Microsoft Azure

---

### .htaacess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

[--------------------------------------------------------](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftisski.com%2F&tab=desktop)

Comment: website URL : http://tisski.com

Comment: Alternative to do would be with Cloudflare, even easier than this, and there the processing load of doing this won't be on your server,  
this might be helpful [Optimising WordPress with Cloudflare](https://vatsalparekh.me/optimising-wordpress-with-cloudflare/)

Comment: Why not compress the files locallcy with a gulp task?

Comment: @vatsalparekh is it stable?

Comment: @Paul may be, but i think the theme is bothering. going for soil plugin

Comment: some of the world's top sites use it! it has a bunch of features other than compression as well

Comment: Enable mod_deflate and mod_expires module modules in apache. Here is the tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-mod_deflate-on-ubuntu-14-04 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-content-caching-on-ubuntu-14-04